# How check if Zebra 105SL printer is OK / ready

Tags: c#, tcp, zebra-printers

I sent data (ZPL) code by TCP/IP - SOCKET. I would like to check status of zebra printer if zebra printer is online and ready.

I google it but I didn’t find solution.

I know static IP address zebra printer and also port.

Answer (score 4):

Send a `~HS` (Host Status)  and check the response

See the [Programming manual](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_ii_programming2.File.tmp/45541L-002_RA.pdf?dvar1=ProductLiterature&dvar2=ZPL%2520II%2520Programming%2520Guide,%2520Volume%2520One%2520%28for%2520printers%2520with%2520firmware%2520x.10%2520%2b%29%2520Rev.%2520A%2520%28en%29&dvar3=104&rct=j&q=ZPL%20manual&ei=qGX_TYO6L6b50gG_q-DWAw&usg=AFQjCNF_qbaDGwpPFzJFAt8L2kV9iayNQg&sig2=Ype1OJwS9MXUbE_c-BATeQ) for the format of the ~HS